# Javascript Event Object ClientY is incorrectly 0

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events, scrollbar, addeventlistener

I wrote a scollbar that works pretty good so far.

This is the order in which it works:

1. when I click on the gripper/scrollbar element `foo.addEventListener( "mousedown", scrollObject.sbar1, false);` is triggered and `sbar1()`
   correctly has the `event.clientY` coordinates of the gripper/scrollbar
   element.
2. I use `foo.addEventListener( "mousemove", sbar2, false);` in
   `sbar1(event)` to get the gripper coordinates real time while it
   slides.

However, the issue is when `sbar2(event)` is called the `event.clientY` coordinates always start at 0. In my logic, the `event.clientY` coordinates should be the same as sbar1's event object coordinates since it is the same element that the `mousedown` event listener.

Why is the `sbar2()` `mousedown` event object (`event.clientY`) coordinates 0? How can I make the event target object be correct as `sbar1()` `event.clientY` is so it can start from there as it takes coordinates real time?

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolioScrollbar">
        <div id="scrollbarTrack"><a id="scrolla" href="#scrollbar"></a></div>
    <div id="pbody">
                      ...all the text stuff...
             </div>
     </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function start() {
    var foo = document.getElementById("scrolla");
        foo.addEventListener( "mousedown", scrollObject.sbar1, false);
        foo.addEventListener( "mouseup", removeAll, false);
        foo.addEventListener( "mouseout", removeAll, false);
    }





var scrollObject = function (event) {
         
    var current = null;
    var move = null;
    var scroll = document.getElementById("scrolla"); // THIS IS THE GRIPPER/SLIDER ELEMENT

    function sbar1(event) {
        console.log("mousedown");
        event.preventDefault();
        current = event.clientY;
        console.log(current);
        console.log("seperate");
        foo.addEventListener( "mousemove", sbar2, false);
    }

    function sbar2(event) {
//      console.log(event.clientY);
        event.preventDefault();
        move = event.clientY - current;
        
        move = Math.abs(move);
        console.log(move);
        scroll.style.top =  move + "px";

    }

    return {
        sbar1: sbar1,
            sbar2: sbar2,
    }
}();
```

For my own learning purposes, I prefer to use Javascript without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out....it was the correct coordinates and not zero. The difference from current was causing it to be 0...not sure how or why.